# Representations of $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ on SAGE/GAP

Tags: representation-theory, sagemath

Let $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$. I want to use SAGE/GAP to write a code that prints image of all irreducible representations of $G$, when applied on the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Is there a SAGE/GAP command available for doing this? I know the command for getting character table on both SAGE or GAP, but I am not really able to find the command for what I need.

Comment: Over what field? And do you have some specific representative in mind (since the image is only determined up to conjugation)?

Comment: I want over $\mathbb{C}$, but not sure what you are asking about representatives. I only want the matrices, when applied at $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But there are an infinite number of such for each (isomorphism class of) irrep. I guess it would make sense to only ask for the diagonal one, but I am not sure why you need them in the first place.

Comment: To be more specific, let us consider the group `G = SL(2, Integers(4))` which has `G.structure_description()` in sage equal to `'A4 : C4'`. It is a group of order $48$, has two generators, `A, B = G.gens()`, and $B$ ist the matrix mentioned above, it has order $4$. Now `[c.degree() for c in G.irreducible_characters()]` is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]`, and consider some rep $\rho$ for some of the `c`'s in the list where the degree is not one. Now use your favorite random matrix of corresponding degree to conjugate $\rho$ with, and get some other rep $\rho'$. Maybe $\rho(B)\ne \rho'(B)$...